# Overwriting in a concurrent queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, race-condition

I'm trying to write a mutex-free (but not lock-free) queue that uses a contiguous range of memory as a circular buffer and four pointers: two for the consumers and two for the producers. It keeps one blank space after the latest pushed element to disambiguate between a full and an empty queue. Here's the implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class concurrent_queue
{
protected:
    T *storage;
    std::size_t s;
    std::atomic<T*> consumer_head, producer_head;

    union alignas(16) dpointer
    {
        struct
        {
            T *ptr;
            std::size_t cnt;
        };
        __int128 val;
    };

    dpointer consumer_pending, producer_pending;

    Allocator alloc;

public:
    concurrent_queue(std::size_t s): storage(nullptr), consumer_head(nullptr), producer_head(nullptr)
    {
        storage = alloc.allocate(s+1);

        consumer_head = storage;
        __atomic_store_n(&(consumer_pending.val), (dpointer{storage, 0}).val, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

        producer_head = storage;
        __atomic_store_n(&(producer_pending.val), (dpointer{storage, 0}).val, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

        this->s = s + 1;
    }
    ~concurrent_queue()
    {
        while(consumer_head != producer_head)
        {
            alloc.destroy(consumer_head.load());
            ++consumer_head;
            if(consumer_head == storage + s)
                consumer_head = storage;
        }
        alloc.deallocate(storage, s);
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool push(U&& e)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            dpointer a;
            a.val = __atomic_load_n(&(producer_pending.val), __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            auto b = consumer_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

            auto next = a.ptr + 1;
            if(next == storage + s) next = storage;

            if(next == b) continue;
            dpointer newval{next, a.cnt+1};
            if(!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(&(producer_pending.val), &(a.val), (newval.val), true, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE, __ATOMIC_RELAXED)) continue;

            alloc.construct(a.ptr, std::forward<U>(e));

            while(!producer_head.compare_exchange_weak(a.ptr, next, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            return true;
        }
    }

    template <typename U>
    bool pop(U& result)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            dpointer a;
            a.val = __atomic_load_n(&(consumer_pending.val), __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            auto b = producer_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

            auto next = a.ptr + 1;
            if(next == storage + s) next = storage;

            if(a.ptr == b) continue;
            dpointer newval{next, a.cnt+1};
            if(!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(&(consumer_pending.val), &(a.val), (newval.val), true, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE, __ATOMIC_RELAXED)) continue;

            result = std::move(*(a.ptr));
            alloc.destroy(a.ptr);

            while(!consumer_head.compare_exchange_weak(a.ptr, next, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

However, when testing with an equal number of separate pushing and popping threads, each pushing/popping an equal, predetermined number of elements before terminating, the some of the popping threads sometimes (not always) get stuck at the first CAS at some point in execution and never terminate, even after all the pushing threads terminate. Since they attempt to pop the same number of elements as the pushing threads push, I suspect that there is overwriting occurring in the pushing thread at some point.

This is my first attempt at writing a concurrent container so I'm very inexperienced with this...I've been staring at this for a while and haven't been able to figure out what is wrong. Can someone more experienced with this spot the issue?

Also, is there any less platform specific way to get a double-width CAS?

Comment: Side note, this is currently written for GCC on x86_64 (because this is the system I'm writing on now).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Most content is this post is actually false. See the comments.

```
        dpointer a;
        a.val = __atomic_load_n(&(producer_pending.val), __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto b = consumer_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Are you absolutely sure that this does what you think it does? this code segment does **not** sequence a.val before b.

The std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); guarantees that memory read operations *after* the fence are not reordered *before* the fence. But nothing prevents  memory operations above the fence from flowing to the bottom. The compiler has complete freedom to move the acquire fence upwards as far as it wants, as long it is not reordered with other fences.

More abstract:

```
a = load relaxed
memory fence acquire -- memory operations below this line may not float upwards
b = load relaxed
```

This compiler may transform it into this:

```
memory fence acquire
b = load relaxed
a = load relaxed
```

But not this:

```
a = load relaxed
b = load relaxed
memory fence acquire
```

Additionally, you should really avoid memory fences and add the acquire/release on the operation itself. This usually leads to better code generation for non-x86 targets. For x86 is doesn't really matter because even a plain `mov` is enough to offer sequential consistency is various cases.

Comment: I'm not sure that I believe you. I've always read that acquire fences prevent loads before it from being reordered with loads and stores after it. A reordering like you indicated would kinda make an acquire fence pointless, it seems to me.

Comment: You are quite correct that plain fences are pointless. There is, in general, nothing that prevents the compiler from moving the fence before main() unless there is an release operation somewhere. The alternative wording on this source: http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ is much easier to understand. Note the 'prevent memory reordering of the read-acquire' part. The 'read-acquire' vs just 'acquire` distinction is important. See also (highly recommended) http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2 35:10 - 54:00

Comment: Check out the part under the heading "With Fences in Portable C++11". If fences worked like you said, then his example wouldn't work; the load of the `Ready` flag could "sink below" the load of `A`, which could cause the value of `A` being read to be incorrect. Say, for example, the reading thread could read `A`, and get unscheduled; then in the meantime, the writing thread could write to `A`, then set the flag; next, the reading thread could get rescheduled and read the ready flag, mistakenly thinking it has a valid value of `A`.

Comment: I spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out where the mistake is. It appears that Herb has an bug in his talk, which is documented here: http://www.preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/. I think that your code snippet does what you think it does, but when even a member of the standard gets this thing wrong, i advise you to stay the hell away from fences and just use acquire/release on the operation itself at least until you got it working correctly. I will update my post to point out my mistake.

Comment: I was actually just doing it as a last ditch effort to see if it helped, honestly. Originally I had acquire on the 16-byte load. It didn't solve anything though, and for some reason I never changed it back. I have a feeling the issue is something other than the fences. Regardless, thank you for trying to help.